# Wrapping navigation properties in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-generation, edmx

Say I have a database table `Node`.

The table contains (among other attributes) the `ParentID` attribute which is a self-referencing FK.

Entity Framework model created from such database table contains two navigational properties:

- `EntityCollection<Node> Node1`
- `Node Node2`

The names are confusing so I changed the names in the designer.

The problem with the approach is that the designer will overwrite my changes when updating the same class.

What I'd like to do is create the partial classes (in another file) that would basically wrap the mentioned navigation properties:

```
public EntityCollection<Node> ChildrenNodes 
{
    get
    {
        return Node1;
    }
    set
    {
        Node1 = value;
    }
}

public Node ParentNode 
{
    get
    {
        return Node2;
    }
    set
    {
        Node2 = value;
    }
}
```

Now, I can recreate the EDMX from scratch and my properties will remain.

However, what I am not sure about is whether this will break the Entity Framework. I don't know how much EF accesses by the name, so I am not sure what would be the consequences of such action.

Would this work normally or would it create some problems?

Comment: Which version are you using? I thought that any name changes were persisted during edmx updates.

Comment: Perhaps they are, however, I remember changing some things in the database (not sure if it was a relationship or a nullable field or something like that) was never seen in the EDMX unless the tables in question were deleted from the model and then readded, thus losing the names.

Comment: That's the case with LINQ-to-SQL but Entity Framework works much better, in my experience.

Comment: @KornelijePetak did you ever get this solved?